# 4x4 Matrix decomposition algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix, game-engine

I'm working on a very large project and I'm trying to revisit and solve a problem that I've been having for quite a while: a **4x4 matrix decomposition algorithm**.

I'm writing a commercial game & simulation engine. It is an API and platform-agnostic engine written entirely in C#. It uses SlimDX as its DirectX back-end, and I'm probably going to stick with OpenTK for the OpenGL back-end. Since I cannot depend on DirectX's or OpenGL's math libraries or data types (e.g., Vector2, Vector3, Quaternion, Matrix, etc) I'm having to write my own types for the engine. I've gotten everything finished up and pretty well optimized; and the API is semantically similar to XNA because I (and many other people) liked XNA's "feel" and felt it was very elegant and powerful. But don't be confused; this project does not use and has nothing to do with XNA. Anyway, I was able to handle everything except ONE thing... Matrix.Decompose!!!

The problem is, I simply have no idea what I'm doing on this... I am a self-taught programmer, and self-taught at virtually everything else (business finance, day trading, German, etc). That's just how I learn. I only had one year and one semester of college, so I have no formal education in complex mathematics. So when I go on Wikipedia and look at formulas for Matrix decomposition it's all Greek to me.... a bunch of funny symbols and diagrams that mean nothing to me lol. I was always a poor math student because math simply escapes me if I can't practically apply it to something (like game programming). For instance, I can write a complex ballistics physics simulation but couldn't even help my girlfriend with her basic physics and calculus homework lol, because it's a bunch of "high-level" theoretical math and I cant bridge the gap to practicality or programming. So I'm just very lost, don't know what I'm doing and highly frustrated...

What I need to do, specifically, is mirror the functionality of Matrix.Decompose found in the XNA Framework and DirectX. I tried to look for the implementation in SlimDX's source and OpenTK's source, but neither had it implemented! SlimDX just defers the work to the native DirectX libraries and OpenTK simply doesn't even have it. As this algorithm is one big, hideously complex beast, I'm not surprised neither development team wanted to implement their own. But I have to.

I've tried turning those whacky formulas on Wikipedia and other sites into a working C# algorithm but I just can't make heads or tails of it. I really need to see a working implementation of it in C, C++ or C#, or have someone help me understand this with pseudo-code or something. I just cannot grasp these formulas and "high-level" mathematics theories. If there's anything you can do to help (a link, a working implementation, some pseudo-code, etc) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try decompiling the XNA implementation with something like ILSpy? It might give you some insight. OR - you could just use XNA's class. Why reinvent the wheel if someone already knows how to do it? Generally, in things like this, many people have worked together to find a solution I could have never found on my own.

Comment: There are many types of matrix decompositions. Which one are you after?

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://callumhay.blogspot.com/2010/10/decomposing-affine-transforms.html) from 3-Blog may help.

Comment: You may also get some help from Bullet Physics which is a C++ library that includes [code](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/btMatrix3x3_8h_source.html) to turn a 3x3 matrix into a quaternion (function getRotation).

Comment: I have to implement my own... remember, platform-agnosticism is one the main points of the engine's design. Using any XNA libraries will mean the method will only work on Windows/XBox where XNA is installed. And it introduces an entirely new dependency...my engine doesn't use XNA at all. I did decompile XNA years ago and I recently looked at their algorithm again, but it looks like that particular method was obfuscated or something. It's full of a bunch of crap that's not even legal C# code, and tons of pointless pointer declarations like "Vector3*** something = undeclaredIdentifier"...

Comment: Is this question asking for a C# library? or asking for the method of performing a matrix decomposition? - the question seems a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DotNetMatrix](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5835/DotNetMatrix-Simple-Matrix-Library-for-NET) which is a C# library for doing all types of matrix transformations, including the [Cholesky Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), which is what I believe you are looking for. In addition, its free and source code is included!

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to use an existing matrix library. Check out ILNumerics, for example. It supports many common matrix decompositions (there is no one 'matrix decomposition'): [http://ilnumerics.net/$FeatureList.html](http://ilnumerics.net/%24FeatureList.html)

That's a commercial license, but because you are selling your engine, maybe it won't be a problem for you.

A free one is [Math.NET](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Linear%20Algebra&referringTitle=Documentation), but the 'Decompositions & Least Squares Problems' section is empty which leads me to believe that they haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: Like I said... specifically, I need to mirror the Matrix decomposition found in DirectX and XNA. I'm not sure which one that is as the documentation gives no hint. It just says it breaks a Matrix down into its translation, rotation and scaling components... the results are a Vector3 for position, a Vector3 for X,Y,Z scaling and a Quaternion for rotation/orientation...